# Why is there always a $TT$-gauge coordinate system comoving with a test particle?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, gauge

In section 35.5 of *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne & Wheeler, when discussing the action of a gravitational wave on two test particles A and B, there is this statement:

[image]

My question is why, to the first order, is there always a $TT$ coordinate system that comoves with particle A? The $TT$ gauge is a special kind of Lorentz gauge (divergence of metric tensor=0 in the weak field theory). If we start from an arbitrary coordinate system (gauge), we need to make a coordinate (gauge) transformation in order to get into a Lorentz gauge and in general the transformation does not keep the space origin point (position of test particle A) unchanged. I don't see anything special about a coordinate system comoving with a test particle, so why we can always find a transformation from it to a Lorentz gauge coordinate system that keeps the space origin point unchanged ("moves with particle A and with its proper reference frame")?